# Making module variables private

Tags: module, fortran

During the last few years, I have been creating several modules with subroutines that I then use for different projects. I am having problems when I define parameter variables in one of those project-specific files that conflict with a variable name defined within those modules. Is it possible to make those names subroutine-private or module-private?

Here is an example. Suppose I have the following module:

```
module mymod

   implicit none
   contains

   subroutine test1(x)
      real, intent(in) :: x(:)
      print *, x**2.0  

   end subroutine test1

end module mymod
```

This module is then called by the main program

```
program main

   use mymod
   implicit none

   real :: y
   real,dimension(2,1),parameter :: x = [1.0,2.0]

   y = 3.0
   call test1(y)

end program main
```

In this case, given that `x` in the main program is defined as a parameter with different dimensions to the `x` in subroutine `test1`, there will be problems when compiling (shape matching rules violated). Is there any way of making `x` in module `mymod` private within the module?

I know an option could be to use "non-common" variable names in my modules or have a list of forbidden names, but that seems complicated at this point (requires editing too many files and lose consistency of notation with books/papers where these procedures are outlined), and would make collaboration with colleagues more difficult.

Comment: Add `PRIVATE` to the module after the `IMPLICIT NONE`.  After the `PRIVATE` statement, add `PUBLIC TEST1`.  This will expose only the test1 entity in the module.

Answer (score 0):

Two different questions in one:

**Why is the example program failing to compile:**

This has nothing to do with public or private, or `x` being defined in the program itself.

It has everything to do with the fact that in the module, `x` as a parameter is defined as a 1-d array, and in the main program, `y` is a scalar.

Try it, remove the declaration of `x` in the main program and it will still fail.

(In fact, the declaration doesn't work like that anyway, you declare `x` as a 2-d array (shape 2, 1), but then give it a 1-d array. You'd have to do something like:

```
real, dimension(2, 1), parameter x = reshape([1.0, 2.0], [2, 1])
```

But to get rid of the error you describe, you either need to change the subroutine interface by removing the `(:)` behind the `real, intent(in) :: x`, or change the call to `call test1([y])`.

**What can you do when 2 modules import different variables of the same name:**

It would be different if you were to say have this:

```
module modA
    implicit none
    real, parameter :: x = 2.0
contains
    subroutine subA(k)
        real, intent(in) :: k
        print *, k*x
    end subroutine subA
end module modA

module modB
    implicit none
    real :: x(3)
end module modB

program progtest
    use modA
    use modB
    implicit none
    call subA(x(1))
end program progtest
```

In this example, it would try to import the variable `x` from both modules.

Ways to avoid it:

1. Make one `x` private:

   ```
   implicit none
   real, parameter, private :: x = 2.0
   ```

   or

   ```
   real, parameter :: x = 2.0
   private :: x
   ```

   or

   ```
   implicit none
   private
   real, parameter :: x = 2.0
   public :: subA
   ```
2. Only import the parts that you need:

   ```
   program progtest
       use modA, only: subA
       use modB
       implicit none
   ...
   ```
3. Rename one or both of the `x`:

   ```
   use modA
   use modB, only: xB => x
   ...
   call subA(xB(1))
   ```

Comment: The key is to make everything in the module `PRIVATE` and only expose those entities in the module that need to be `PUBLIC`.

Comment: In the example OP posted, the issue was absolutely not the private/public issue. His problem, according to the example, was the parameter type mismatch.